# How to spawn another sprite after one is "removed"

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a game with similar concepts to the snake game for a project. I want to make it such that when the player "eats" the "food", another one appears randomly elsewhere.

I have tried several codes from here and other sources but I can't seem to get them to run. There will always be different errors.

This is the code that I am using for now. I got it from online and it worked for the person but it doesn't work for me. My guess is that `list.remove` might be the problem with this code but I don't know how to edit it:

```
food_collide = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player,food_list,False)

    for food in  food_collide:
        score += 1
        food_list.remove(food)
        all_sprite_list.remove(food)
        food.update()
        all_sprite_list.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me that you never create a new instance of `Food()` after you kill the previous one (when eated by the player). So obviously the game doesn't spawn a new food.

This quick fix of the `for food in food_collide` should works:

```
for food in food_collide:
    score += 1
    food_list.remove(food)
    newfood = Food()
    food_list.add(newfood)
    all_sprite_list.add(newfood)
    all_sprite_list.remove(food)
    food_list.update()
    all_sprite_list.update()
```